# nodeJs mongoose transaction for multi document operation

Tags: node.js, mongoose, transactions

I'm trying to use mongoose transaction for multi document operation with node.js and it does not working

I have many Models and I would like to make some database updates in diferents data models.

Firstly I get the data
Secondly I update and save
Thirdly I update another model
Fourthly and at the end, I make another update in another model

The problem is that after the first update, nothing happens

```
import User from '../../models/user'
import Caso from '../../models/caso'
import Pessoa from '../../models/pessoa'
import Ocorrencia from '../../models/ocorrencia'
import Organizacao from '../../models/organizacao'
import Embarcacao from '../../models/embarcacao'
import Aeronave from '../../models/aeronave'
import Documento from '../../models/documento'

const getEntity = {
  caso: (id, session) => Caso.findById(id, {session}),
  pessoa: (id, session) => Pessoa.findById(id, {session}),
  organizacao: (id, session) => Organizacao.findById(id, {session}),
  ocorrencia: (id, session) => Ocorrencia.findById(id, {session}),
  embarcacao: (id, session) => Embarcacao.findById(id, {session}),
  aeronave: (id, session) => Aeronave.findById(id, {session}),
  documento: (id, session) => Documento.findById(id, {session})
}

//Remove all card relation from its coin relation entity
const pullEntityCoin = {
  caso: ({id, entity, session}) => Caso.updateMany({}, {$pull: {[entity]: id}}, {session}),
  pessoa: ({id, entity, session}) => Pessoa.updateMany({}, {$pull: {[entity]: id}}, {session}),
  organizacao: ({id, entity, session}) => Organizacao.updateMany({}, {$pull: {[entity]: id}}, {session}),
  ocorrencia: ({id, entity, session}) => Ocorrencia.updateMany({}, {$pull: {[entity]: id}}, {session}),
  embarcacao: ({id, entity, session}) => Embarcacao.updateMany({}, {$pull: {[entity]: id}}, {session}),
  aeronave: ({id, entity, session}) => Aeronave.updateMany({}, {$pull: {[entity]: id}}, {session}),
  documento: ({id, entity, session}) => Documento.updateMany({}, {$pull: {[entity]: id}}, {session})
}

//Add all coin relation entity to each entity relation
const pushEntityCoin = {
  caso: ({id, entity, ids, session}) => Caso.updateMany({_id: { $in: ids}}, {$push: {[entity]: id}}, {upsert: true }, {session}),
  pessoa: ({id, entity, ids, session}) => Pessoa.updateMany({_id: { $in: ids}}, {$push: {[entity]: id}}, {upsert: true }, {session}),
  organizacao: ({id, entity, ids, session}) => Organizacao.updateMany({_id: { $in: ids}}, {$push: {[entity]: id}}, {upsert: true }, {session}),
  ocorrencia: ({id, entity, ids, session}) => Ocorrencia.updateMany({_id: { $in: ids}}, {$push: {[entity]: id}}, {upsert: true }, {session}),
  embarcacao: ({id, entity, ids, session}) => Embarcacao.updateMany({_id: { $in: ids}}, {$push: {[entity]: id}}, {upsert: true }, {session}),
  aeronave: ({id, entity, ids, session}) => Aeronave.updateMany({_id: { $in: ids}}, {$push: {[entity]: id}}, {upsert: true }, {session}),
  documento: ({id, entity, ids, session}) => Documento.updateMany({_id: { $in: ids}}, {$push: {[entity]: id}}, {upsert: true }, {session})
}

const updateEntityCoin = async (_, { entityCoinInput }, { req }) => {
  const { _id, entity, coin, ids } = entityCoinInput
  console.log(entityCoinInput);
  if (!req.isAuth) {
    throw new Error('Unauthenticated user!')
  }

  const session = await db.startSession()
  try {
    await session.withTransaction(async () => {

      const creator = await User.findById(req.userId, { session })
      if (!creator) throw new Error('Usuário inexistente!')

      const card = await getEntity[entity](_id, session)
      if (!card) throw new Error('Caso não encontrado!')

      //Remove all ids from coin node and includes the new coin array
      card[coin] = ids

      card.logs.push({
        ordem: new Date().toISOString(),
        _id: req.userId
      })
      await card.save({session})

      var res = await pullEntityCoin[coin]({id: _id, entity, session })
      console.log({res});

      res = await pushEntityCoin[coin]({id: _id, entity, ids, session })
      console.log({res});

      const exists = creator[entity].find(
        (id) => id.toString() === _id.toString()
      )
      if (!exists) {
        creator[entityCoinInput.entity].push(entity)
        await creator.save()
      }

      await session.commitTransaction()
    })
    // console.log(entity)
  } catch (err) {
    await session.abortTransaction()
    throw err
  } finally {
    await session.endSession();
  }
}

module.exports = {
  Query: {},
  Mutation: {
    updateEntityCoin
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Pass session in async..

```
await session.withTransaction(async (session) => {
```

Comment: Many thanks Sunan Stc. Make sense. Will try it.